# single image store multiple times

Tags: android, image, android-layout

Want to store image only single time but image store 3 times in folder all functions are called one time only but images store 3 time instead of one time.

```
private ImageChooserManager imageChooserManager;
private File mFileTemp;
```

Here is my setOnClickListener

```
 LinDriverImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // showchooseImagePopup(getActivity(), "user");
            final MaterialSimpleListAdapter adapter = new MaterialSimpleListAdapter(new MaterialSimpleListAdapter.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onMaterialListItemSelected(MaterialDialog dialog, int index, MaterialSimpleListItem item) {
                    if (index == 0) {

                        chooseImageFromGallery();
                        Log.d("imagechoser", "LinDriverImage");

                        imageStatus = "user";
                        materialDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    if (index == 1) {

                        chooseImageFromCamera();
                        imageStatus = "user";
                        materialDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                }
            });

            adapter.add(new MaterialSimpleListItem.Builder(ActivityDriverProfile.this)
                    .content("Gallery Image")
                    .icon(R.drawable.ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp)
                    .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                    .build());
            adapter.add(new MaterialSimpleListItem.Builder(ActivityDriverProfile.this)
                    .content("Capture Image")
                    .icon(R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_black_24dp)
                    .backgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                    .build());

            materialDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(ActivityDriverProfile.this)
                    .title("Choose option")
                    .adapter(adapter, null)
                    .show();

        }
    });
```

I use chooseImage for choose the image

```
  private void chooseImageFromCamera() {
    imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this, ChooserType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE, "myfolder", true);
    imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(ActivityDriverProfile.this);
    try {
        imageChooserManager.choose();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think may be these lines of code have some issue but i dont know onImageChosen is also callsed once only.

```
@Override
public void onImageChosen(final ChosenImage chosenImage) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (chosenImage != null) {
                isPicChange = "1";
                mFileTemp = new File(chosenImage.getFileThumbnailSmall());

                if (imageStatus.equals("user")) {
                    Picasso.with(ActivityDriverProfile.this).load(mFileTemp).transform(new CircleTransform()).resize(300, 300).centerCrop()
                            .skipMemoryCache().into(reviewUserImage);

                }
                if (imageStatus.equals("nicfront")) {
                    Picasso.with(ActivityDriverProfile.this).load(mFileTemp).resize(470, 300).centerCrop()
                            .skipMemoryCache().into(nicfront);
                }
                if (imageStatus.equals("nicback")) {
                    Picasso.with(ActivityDriverProfile.this).load(mFileTemp).resize(470, 300).centerCrop()
                            .skipMemoryCache().into(nicback);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onError(String s) {
}



 private void chooseImageFromGallery() {
    // int chooserType = ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE;
    imageChooserManager = new ImageChooserManager(this, ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE, "myfolder", true);
    imageChooserManager.setImageChooserListener(ActivityDriverProfile.this);
    try {
        imageChooserManager.choose();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && (requestCode == ChooserType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE || requestCode == ChooserType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE)) {

            imageChooserManager.submit(requestCode, data);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try to print (imageStatus.equals("user"))  and check what it returns.

Comment: it will return true when user image select

Comment: imageStatus = ? return

Comment: condition will be true (imageStatus.equals("user"))

Comment: but mFileTemp=/storage/emulated/0/myfolder/1527060440759_fact_2.jpg

Comment: image names are
1527060440759_fact_2
1527060440759_fact_1
1527060440759

Answer (score 0):

I only use this and resolve my issue

```
   mFileTemp = new File(chosenImage.getFilePathOriginal());
                deleteImage(new File(chosenImage.getFileThumbnail()));
                deleteImage(new File(chosenImage.getFileThumbnailSmall()));
```